# how to keep individual sessions in MVC 4 app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session-cookies

I am quite new to mvc4, I have created an app that's is stored on our webserver, that connects to a another server based on your log in details, and retrieves a balance amongst other things,  this then allows you to deposit an amount via Paypal, and then redirects to back to the web app where it updates the other server with the amount, this is all fine when I log in on my own, but if I get my colleagues to log in at the same time, when we redirect back from paypal, we sometimes get someone else's details been displayed on our devices.

I was thinking that it could be session related ?? is there away to have the app have multiple connections, and to keep them all independent ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `static` variables. Never use them in a web application, unless you're making an in-memory cache.

A possible solution is to store a session ID in a cookie and retrieve the session data at the beginning of a request.

Comment: I do have a database that I am using to store the paypal token, user name and deposit amount, would it be worth storing a unique id in there, and maybe some more details ??

Comment: There are multiple ways to manage sessions. You'll have to do some research and see what approach fits best in your case.